# SQL: Get results of time series of days backwards

Tags: sql, arrays, datetime, google-bigquery, unnest

Given is a table of stock values for entities saved every day. I would like to get:

Give all entities which are out of stock (Qty = 0) today and were not out of stock the day before.

And this for the day before yesterday compared to the day before the day beford yesterday. And so on.

My approach works, but I have to create the part in the WHERE condition manually.

How about a query for the whole year 2019?

```
#standardSQL
WITH
  TableStockDaily AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-10 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1001 AS EntityId, 0 as Qty UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-10 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1002 AS EntityId, 0 as Qty UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-10 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1003 AS EntityId, 1 as Qty UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-11 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1001 AS EntityId, 1 as Qty UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-11 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1002 AS EntityId, 1 as Qty UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-11 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1003 AS EntityId, 0 as Qty UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-12 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1001 AS EntityId, 0 as Qty UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-12 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1002 AS EntityId, 1 as Qty UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-12 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1003 AS EntityId, 1 as Qty UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-13 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1001 AS EntityId, 1 as Qty UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-13 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1002 AS EntityId, 0 as Qty UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-13 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1003 AS EntityId, 0 as Qty UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-14 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1001 AS EntityId, 0 as Qty UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-14 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1002 AS EntityId, 0 as Qty UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-14 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1003 AS EntityId, 1 as Qty UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-15 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1001 AS EntityId, 1 as Qty UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-15 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1002 AS EntityId, 1 as Qty UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-15 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1003 AS EntityId, 0 as Qty UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-16 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1001 AS EntityId, 1 as Qty UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-16 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1002 AS EntityId, 1 as Qty UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-10-16 00:00:00 UTC') AS ExportDate, 1003 AS EntityId, 1 as Qty
  )
SELECT
  sd1.ExportDate AS DateOutOfStock,
  sd2.ExportDate AS DateNotOutOfStock,
  sd1.EntityId AS EntityId,
  sd1.Qty AS Qty1,
  sd2.Qty AS Qty2
FROM
  TableStockDaily sd1
LEFT JOIN
  TableStockDaily sd2
ON
  sd1.EntityId = sd2.EntityId
WHERE
  sd1.Qty = 0
  AND sd2.Qty > 0
  AND sd1.ExportDate > sd2.ExportDate
  AND
  (
    ( 
      DATE(sd1.ExportDate) <= DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
      AND DATE(sd1.ExportDate) >= DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -2 DAY)
      AND DATE(sd2.ExportDate) <= DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -2 DAY)
      AND DATE(sd2.ExportDate) > DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -3 DAY)
    )
    OR
    ( 
      DATE(sd1.ExportDate) <= DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -2 DAY)
      AND DATE(sd1.ExportDate) >= DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -3 DAY)
      AND DATE(sd2.ExportDate) <= DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -3 DAY)
      AND DATE(sd2.ExportDate) > DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -4 DAY)
    )
    OR
    ( 
      DATE(sd1.ExportDate) <= DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -3 DAY)
      AND DATE(sd1.ExportDate) >= DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -4 DAY)
      AND DATE(sd2.ExportDate) <= DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -4 DAY)
      AND DATE(sd2.ExportDate) > DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -5 DAY)
    )
    OR
    ( 
      DATE(sd1.ExportDate) <= DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -4 DAY)
      AND DATE(sd1.ExportDate) >= DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -5 DAY)
      AND DATE(sd2.ExportDate) <= DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -5 DAY)
      AND DATE(sd2.ExportDate) > DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -6 DAY)
    )
    OR
    ( 
      DATE(sd1.ExportDate) <= DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -5 DAY)
      AND DATE(sd1.ExportDate) >= DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -6 DAY)
      AND DATE(sd2.ExportDate) <= DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -6 DAY)
      AND DATE(sd2.ExportDate) > DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for `LAG()`. This window function can be used to recover the value of a given column within a group of recrods (here, records sharing the same `EntityID`) and according to a sorting criteria (here `ExportDate`):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        EntityId,
        ExportDate AS DateOutOfStock,
        Qty AS QtyOutOfStock,
        LAG(ExportDate) OVER(PARTITION BY EntityId ORDER BY ExportDate) AS DateNotOutOfStock,
        LAG(Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY EntityId ORDER BY ExportDate) AS QtyNotOutOfStock
    FROM
      TableStockDaily sd1
) x
WHERE QtyOutOfStock = 0 AND QtyNotOutOfStock > 0
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. It works. I checked it for different date and results are the same.